# How can I read an openssl aes-256-cbc encrypted file without creating an unencrypted file in Linux?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have an encrypted file and to decrypt it I use the command:

```
 openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in encrypted_file -out unencrypted_file
```

But when I do this an unencrypted file is created which I have to delete when I am done. This means that if somebody gets my computer and uses some kind of data recovery tool they can get the unencrypted file. Is there any way to a access the data in the encrypted file without creating another file?

Comment: Hi, otus. I am new to stackexchange and I wasn't sure where to post the question. I will close the question but could you please point me in the right direction as to where i should post this question?

Comment: Does simply using `-out /dev/stdout` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a linux, and have a couple ideas...

## Extract to RAM

An easy way would be to still create the decrypted file, but don't write it to disk. Put it in ram, with for instance a **ramfs** or **tmpfs** filesystem. Though, problems could be:

- The file may not fit in ram
- ramfs may increase in size until all ram is used (subsequently probably crashing)
- tmpfs [*may be written to your on-disk swap*](http://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk) (also see that link for the difference between tmpfs & ramfs).

Your `/tmp` or other folders (like `/run`, `/run/shm`, `/run/user`) may already be mounted as a tmpfs, you can check with `mount|grep tmpfs`.

---

To create a new **tmpfs** you can do this (optionally with a size in bytes if you wish, similar to `-o size=16384`, I think it defaults to half of ram):

```
sudo mount -v -t tmpfs  tmpfs /mountpoint
```

---

To use the older **ramfs**, that will not be written to swap, but doesn't have size limits this should work:

```
sudo mount -v -t ramfs  ramfs /mountpoint
```

Though the [link above](http://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk) warns:

> ramfs file systems cannot be limited in size like a disk based file system which is limited by it’s capacity. ramfs will continue using memory storage until the system runs out of RAM and likely crashes or becomes unresponsive

Also, [kernel documentation here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) also warns & says:

> One downside of ramfs is you can keep writing data into it until you fill
>   up all memory, and the VM can't free it because the VM thinks that files
>   should get written to backing store (rather than swap space), but ramfs hasn't
>   got any backing store.  Because of this, only root (or a trusted user) should
>   be allowed write access to a ramfs mount.
>
> A **ramfs** derivative called **tmpfs** was created to add size limits, and the ability
>   to write the data to swap space.  Normal users can be allowed write access to
>   tmpfs mounts.  See Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt for more information.

## Extract to an encrypted device or folder

If the above RAM problems are too much, you could use another program to encrypt the file on-disk *again*, but so it can be read & used unencrypted "on-the-fly" (ex. the decrypted version looks & acts like a regular file, but stays encrypted on-disk). You could create an encrypted partition or container file with dm[-crypt/LUKS/truecrypt with cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup), or an encrypted folder with [eCryptFS](http://ecryptfs.org/) or [EncFS](http://www.arg0.net/#!encfs/c1awt), and then decrypt your file there.

- For example, to create a 1GB LUKS container file with ext4, mounted to the folder `mountpoint-folder`, do this:

  ```
  head -c 1G /dev/zero > 1G
  sudo cryptsetup -v luksFormat 1G
  sudo cryptsetup -v luksOpen 1G container
  sudo mkfs.ext4 -v /dev/mapper/container
  sudo mount -v /dev/mapper/container <mountpoint-folder>
  ```

  And then decrypt your file into the `mountpont-folder` where it will be readable, even though it's written to disk encrypted again.
- eCryptFS is already installed in Linux Mint, Ubuntu, and many other distributions, do you may only need to run `ecryptfs-setup-private` and then use the created `~/Private` folder.
- EncFS probably has to be installed (similar to `apt-get install encfs`) and then see it's [man page here](https://github.com/vgough/encfs/blob/master/encfs/encfs.pod) or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/encfs), a command like `encfs ~/.secret ~/decrypted` should work.

  Also, EncFS has a neat `--reverse` feature that "*takes as source plaintext data and produces enciphered data on-demand. This can be useful for creating remote encrypted backups, where you do not wish to keep the local files unencrypted.*"

Comment: Do you have a source proving that "tmpfs may be written to your disk cache"? (It doesn't sound making sense at all)

Comment: but of course, adding to answer now. From this basic search FYI https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=tmpfs+may+be+written+to+swap

Comment: Btw there are kernel docs for tmpfs and ramfs (and more): https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Comment: Excellent kernel doc links, I'm adding their "differences" paragraph, thanks @TomYan

Answer (score 4):

If the data can be handled by a program that accepts input from stdin, you can use piping as well. For example:
`openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in encrypted_plain_text_file | less`